# Can an iframe specify a whitelist of domains that can access its innerHTML, contentWindow, contentDocument etc?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain-policy

Can a iframe specify a whitelist of domains that can access its innerHTML, contentWindow, contentDocument etc ?

what I mean is for example

```
<body>
<iframe src="someotherdomain.com" id="frame"/>
</body>
<script>
console.log(document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.someProp);
//this would fail, as its cross domain iframe
</script>
```

what if the iframe can specify in its response header similar to x-frame-allow, a whitelist of domains/patterns that are allowed to access its innerHTML, contentWindow etc. Is there any early stage such proposal/RFC in progress or has this been discussed before?

Comment: If you just want to communicate between the parent/child window, the best option is to use window.postMessage(). Both windows can register even listeners and send data back and forth.

Comment: @Siva yes indeed. but here I don't control the javascript of the iframe in any way

Comment: post message wont work cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

Try setting response headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.domain.com which would allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Refer:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin